# How to extract MPFS filesystem?

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, firmware

I'm working with binwalk and i came across a MPFS filesystem which I can't extract:

```
Scan Time:     2013-05-27 12:58:20
Signatures:    196
Target File:   _1081A47.tar.extracted/dev_flash_017.tar.aa.2013_04_19_031009
MD5 Checksum:  78d90cb5abbe619f2fcbc10483f9d774

DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6584351     0x64781F    MPFS (Microchip) filesystem, version 223.241, 3334 file entries
```

This is from `binwalk -e PS3UPDAT.PUP`, `cd` to extracted folder and then `binwalk -ey filesystem *` on the latest firmware of PS3.
http://us.playstation.com/support/systemupdates/ps3/pc_update/index.htm

How it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely a false positive. The version field looks bogus, and I doubt Sony would leave unencrypted data in the update file.

Comment: Isn't the best way to find it out is to extract the filesystem? The problem is I can't find such tool in google.